National passport and travel document for foreigners: Which to get visas on?
I'm a citizen of a country that doesn't let me change my gender marker (at least without "the surgery", a court case and invasive checks ordered by court), and a resident of Germany, which allows people (incl. foreigners) to change their name and gender marker. Today I changed (only) my gender marker here, which will not be recognized by my country of nationality.
As a result of this I will be given a "travel document for foreigners" ("reiseausweis für ausländer"), as German residence permits are legally not ID documents, and must match ID documents.
According to the inner cover of the travel document, it does entitle me to travel to Germany (when combined with a residence permit, which I do have). As far as I know, this is also what I'll be expected to enter Germany with, as the residence permit is tied to a given passport number.

(src: https://www.consilium.europa.eu/prado/en/DEU-JO-01002/image-366794.html)
To simplify travel to countries that already require me to get visas (deciding which passport to give and when, especially for those without exit immigration like UK where I'm requested to go to document check and give documents proving I can enter Germany), I was thinking that I might get visas on the travel document instead.
Does anyone have any information on this process, or any anecdotes? I couldn't find much on this topic while searching online. I don't recall any country I applied for a visa from having an obvious way to submit my foreigners' travel document instead of passport of nationality.
(This is a different and hopefully simpler question than those with a travel document for refugees, as I am not a refugee and retain my passport of nationality. I also imagine this gets more complicated for those that have also changed their first names, as for me right now an APIS match based on firstname/lastname/birthdate is possible.)
(I know that the simple answer for me is "just get it in your country of nationality passport, it's less headache", but I'm looking for a more comprehensive answer, especially one that also accounts for the case of firstname mismatch, as that'd be more useful to everyone else, according to the government employee that handled my change today, only changing just gender marker is rare and potentially disallowed in my.)

If this fits expats.se more, let's move it there. For me it was a split: having a foreigners TD is very much an expat problem, but visa questions are more fitting here, and get more eyes on them here.

I hope you can get some good answers; but this is a very particular circumstance (much rarer than refugee travel documents held by millions of people with the backing of several international treaties).

However, answers concerning the use of refugee travel documents may still be helpful in so far the acceptance of alternative documents is concerned. And a country that does not recognize or give difficulties to holders of refugee travel documents is unlikely to facilitate the use of an alternative document issued to non-citizens.

@xngtng I struggled to find information even on refugee TDs and getting visas, tbh.

Non-standard travel documents (I.e. anything but a regular passport) are quickly a source of a lot of issues. One possible starting point is the IATA Travel Centre (based on Timatic): it allows you to select your travel document type among a very long list, though I’m not sure which one I would pick for that document. “Travel documents” (in the specific rather than generic sense) usually mean travel documents for refugees (of which there are several sorts). Does your document have an MRZ (the two lines with lots of <)? If so, what are the first 2 characters of the first line? Is it biometric?

PRADO tells me it does have an MRZ and is biometric, which helps. But my hunch is that it the answer will be on a country-by-country basis, and not necessarily easy to find.


I don't recall any country I applied for a visa from having an obvious way to submit my foreigners' travel document instead of passport of nationality.

Generally you just pretend it's a passport and submit it instead.  Not every consular service bothers to add confusing language such as "passport or passport-replacing travel document" for the sake of being precise.  The majority of applicants will have no idea what that means and it will just make things more confusing.  But consulates generally do accept such documents, at least from refugees and stateless people.
I would be inclined to try to get visas in the German document where possible, since it matches your present name and gender, and, where countries prefer your national passport, to use that instead.  On any trip where you need to use both, you'll probably also want to carry a copy of any court orders or other legal documents that changed your name or gender, to establish that the German document and the passport do indeed refer to the same person.

Note, the german change document does not have much, it's just an A5 of data in german, with no information on old name or gender. To citizens they issue a new birth certificate on an A4 (which in Convention on the Issue of Multilingual Extracts from Civil Status Records format wouldn't have past info), this is what they issue to foreigners as an equivalent, which is prob why it has no historic info. I'll carry it around anyways.

@ave if you're travelling to a country with decently staffed embassies or consulates you could ask them directly beforehand just to make sure. But I'd agree with phoog that it's gonna work (except for countries with a hard anti-LGBTQ stance, if those find out they may make a fuss on purpose based on these technicalities)

@Hobbamok In my experience, reaching actual humans that know things at embassies has been difficult. Also in case of UK, you have to pay to ask questions. It's only 2.74GBP, but that's pretty annoying. But yeah, if I can reach them or find concrete advice on their website that'd be my first route, ofc.

@Hobbamok, ave: indeed, my experience is similar; I've found that reaching actual humans often seems impossible, yet there are stories on this site of people not only managing to reach actual humans but even finding them to be helpful.  Experience is going to be widely variable depending on the country, on the consular post, and, if one does manage to reach someone, on the person you've reached.

@ave I looked for something in the US Foreign Affairs Manual on the subject of these documents and didn't find anything.  I know that they prefer to issue G visas for UN officers in the national passport rather than the UN laissez-passer, but how they'd react in your situation I can only guess at this point, and in the absence of an official policy (which I may have overlooked, or which may be redacted from the public edition of the FAM, or which may in fact not exist) it will surely depend on the individual officer.  You certainly can't use ESTA with the German document.

Passport is a travel document. "Travel Document" is a general class of documents that allow proving identity (and potentially citizenship) across borders.
The main difference between the subset of travel documents called "passport" and the rest is that latter part - they prove citizenship. Passports are only issued to the citizens of the entity issuing it (with the notable exceptions of the UK, and to lesser extent the US where the difference between nationals and citizens is internal only).
Thus you can submit your German travel document in lieu of passport with your visa applications. There are countries that do not recognize some documents. For example, Malta doesn't recognize an Israeli travel document in lieu of passport. You'll need to check with the intended consulate if they recognize this document.
However, if you would be entitled for visa waiver, evisa, or visa on arrival based on your nationality/citizenship - that entitlement may not extend to travel documents. Especially in the case where the travel document is not from the country of which you're citizen - you're very likely to be required a visa almost anywhere in the world (although I believe a German travel document allows visa free access to Schengen countries).

German TD should allow visa free entry to Schengen combined with a german residence permit, yes. I'm more concerned about countries potentially not wanting TDs for visa applications if you have a proper passport, or may look down on it as they're often issued to refugees (even confusing it with a refugee TD and applying processing accordingly, possibly).

@ave refugees are issued a different document. Whether they'd look down on it or not is hard to answer, but it does show that you're somewhere where you don't technically belong and you don't want to go back to where you do, which may raise concerns.

yeah, I'm aware, though it looks similar and as stated elsewhere this one is fairly uncommon, border staff are known to sometimes not be convinced it's a real passport when one presents a rare passport (liechtenstein etc). I don't get your point about "belonging", but if I get it even partly correctly, a residence permit proves roughly the same thing and I have to submit that when applying for a visa here anyways. IME presenting my german residence at random borders has the opposite effect: it proves ties to a well-off country

@ave right, which is why I said it's hard to answer. Visa officers by default assume the worst and you have to prove you're not going to overstay, so this document makes this task somewhat more difficult. Residency can be revoked, citizenship is much harder to take away.
